# EntityRef adding unwanted record

Tags: .net, entityreference

I have an `BookOrder` object which has an `EntityRef` var to a `Book` object.  The objects are linked by book Id.  When inserting a new `BookOrder` record, a new `Book` record also gets inserted into the `book` table.  How do I stop this, and just insert the `BookOrder` record? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so after searching all day I was finally able find what my problem was and how to fix it at the following link.

http://aspnetking.blogspot.com/2009/03/foreign-key-issue-for-update-in-linq.html

Oh, and I'll be sure to accept this as the answer instead of the "answer" that was nothing more than someones attempt to up their **reputation** by providing no real help at all.  **Perhaps** you should actually attempt to help someone if you intend to "answer" their question.

Comment: the link your provided is not available, can you show me another link?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this, as it would create an order for a book that doesn't exist.

That's why the book gets automatically created.

You should perhaps say what technology you'r using, that would make it easier to give a more accurate answer.

And you should also accept answers to your questions, it's important for your own reputation.

Comment: Okay. Using C# LINQ to SQL Classes .dbml file.  Dragged two tables from a SQL Server 2008 database on the .dbml diagram thing (Don't really know what else to call it) .  The table Book has a relationship with the BookOrder table via the BookId fields.  This created the EntityRef propertiy in the .dbml/BookOrder object.